# problem displaying diacritics in PDF files

Tags: drupal, pdf

on a drupal 7 install with civiCRM 4.7.0 we have a problem displaying diacritics in PDF files. diacritics are shown as ?

thank you in advance

Comment: More details worth including might be how you're generating the PDF (the toolkit you're using, eg wkhtmltopdf or dompdf), and the specific CiviCRM workflow which is generating incorrect PDFs for you. Try reproducing your issue on demo.civicrm.org servers and see if the same issue happens there?